# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

Im trying to create an user in my intelliJ spring boot jpa application but this error happens

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet] with root cause
>
> oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02289: Sequence doesnt exist

So i tried this solution that i find but still doesnt work

```
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_CADASTRO", sequenceName = "SEQ_CADASTRO", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_CADASTRO", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

Code in my Application now

```
 @Id
    @Column(name = "UTILIZADOR_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_CADASTRO", sequenceName = "SEQ_CADASTRO", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_CADASTRO", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private BigInteger utilizadorId;
```

This is my create Bll

```
 public static void createUtilizador(SpringWebMVC.s2.DAL.Utilizador  uti){
        if(factory == null)
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

        if (em == null) em = factory.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(uti);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your application.properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create sequence in the database as below?
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 0
MINVALUE 0
MAXVALUE 100
NOCYCLE
NOCACHE;

Or did you add below property in application properties file
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
It will create sequence in the database if not excit.

Comment: Please execute this on database console.    select a_seq.nextval from dual;.  Check sequence whether excit or not